# this.id captured into a var changes during subsequent 'each' loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So check out this jsfiddle; [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/w3fPS/)

What I'm trying to do;

Series of "links" each with an initially hidden div of content beneath them.

Clicking on a link should A) show the div content for that link B) if any other link's div content is open, close it.

ie, only one div content section should be open at a time.

At the top of the `click` handler I'm capturing the clicked link's id into a var. However during the `each` call this appears to be updating (as shown by the alert call I have in there for demo purposes).

```
$('.link-part').click(function() {
    var clickedId = this.id;
    $('.link-part').each(function(i, obj) {
        alert(clickedId + " " + obj.id);
        if(clickedId = obj.id) {
            $('#' + obj.id + 'div').slideToggle(500);
        } else {
            if('none' != $('#' + obj.id + 'div').css('display')) {
                $('#' + obj.id + 'div').slideToggle(200);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});​
```

Why is this? How do I get it to be a non-mutable variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just missed out an equals sign when doing a comparison, change:

```
if(clickedId = obj.id) {
```

to

```
if(clickedId == obj.id) {
```

Comment: Haha nice. Always something obvious like that. Cheers. I wonder how many developer man-hours have been wasted in total (by everyone, everywhere, ever) because assignment and comparison, two significantly different operations, are separated by only one repeated character!

Comment: I've made this mistake many, many times.  It happens most often when I'm using VB.Net then swap into writing some JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

as an alternative you don't need `each` loop for this effect, try this:

```
$('.link-part').click(function() {
    $('.div-part:visible').slideUp()
    $(this).next('.div-part').slideDown()
    return false;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w3fPS/4/)